# Return value of the method is never used

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

how to write a model class with getters and setters defined and returned

```
public Team(Long id,String queue,Number answered,Number offered, Number answerRate,Number abandoned,String avgAbandonTime,Number totalTalkTime,Number avgTalkTime, Number unmanaged) {
    this.id = id;
    this.queue = queue;
    this.answered = answered;
    this.offered = offered;
    this.answerRate = answerRate;
    this.abandoned = abandoned;
    this.avgAbandonTime = avgAbandonTime;
    this.totalTalkTime = totalTalkTime;
    this.avgTalkTime =  avgTalkTime;
    this.unmanaged=unmanaged;
}
//getters and setters..
}
```

Comment: You have editor ? Eclipse or else. Just right click and generate getters ans setters

Comment: i have intelli j editor

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#generate-getters-setters

Answer (score 0):

Every setter method's name must have `set` prefix & getter method's name must have `get` followed by camel cased property name. Example:

```
public void setQueue(String queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public String getQueue() {
    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Result of 'Team.getQueue()' is ignored

Comment: Team team = new Team(); team.getQueue()

Comment: this is the error that i am getting when i move mouseover  any of the getcall,      Return value of the method is never used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ the IDE has the option to automatically generate getters and setters for your class using "alt + ins" [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGsd3.png)

If you're getting that the "Return value of the method is never used." it is pretty straightforward, it means that you haven't referred to any of those methods anywhere at the moment.

Comment: where to reffer and how?

Comment: When you declare and initialize the object of class Team (for example Team sportsTeam = new Team()) you would be able to refer to the public getters and setter like this:
sportsTeam.setQueue("first");
and then using the get method -> sportsTeam.getQueue(); you would be able to retrieve "first".

Comment: getting an error (java.io.EOFException: null)..

Comment: can you link the code where you initialize the variable?

Comment: In the model class i have taken an entity fields of a table as  variables